# How to get Javascript function varible in php code for store in DB

Tags: javascript, php, bing-maps

I want this two variable in php code. Please let me help how to do that

```
function UpdateLocation(position) {
   latitude = position.coords.latitude;
   longitude = position.coords.longitude;

   //move map to new location and zoom in
   map.setView({ center: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude 
       }, zoom: 16, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial });
}
```

Comment: function UpdateLocation(position) {
            latitude = position.coords.latitude;
            longitude = position.coords.longitude;

            //move map to new location and zoom in
            map.setView({ center: { latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude }, zoom: 16, mapTypeId: Microsoft.Maps.MapTypeId.aerial });
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

You cannot pass JavaScript variables to PHP directly if you are looking to store these values in your database, you need to create an API in PHP and make a POST request from your JavaScript code to the API.